# Property 'Content' was not found in type 'FrameworkElement' using DataTrigger

Tags: wpf

I'm new to WPF. 
I'm trying to display a `ToolTip` on a `ListBox` item only when the grouping is equal to "Search Results". 
I'm getting an error that says :

> "Property 'Content' was not found in type 'FrameworkElement'."

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the code below?

```
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=code}">
                        <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=grouping}" Value="Search Results">
                                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Path=grouping}"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </ToolTip.Triggers>
                            </ToolTip>
                        </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

It works ok without the trigger like the code below so it confuses me why it says that the property was not found.

```
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=code}">
                        <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip Content="{Binding Path=grouping}" />
                        </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: add TargetType="ListBoxItem" to the <DataTemplate>. Does it works?

Comment: Change `Content` to `ToolTip.Content`.

Comment: There is no TargetType property on a DataTemplate. Changing Content to Tooltip.Content doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you getting a run-time exception?

Comment: no, it's a compile-time error

Comment: put the ToolTip triggers in style of the ToolTip, and on the Style add TargetType=ToolTip.

Comment: Oh hey, I'm sorry. I was caught up with something else. I'll take a look again tomorrow. I doubt something is wrong with the binding though as the binding works fine when I do it without the trigger but I'll take a look again nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

The `Triggers` collection of `FrameworkElement` is only for event triggers, not for `DataTrigger`s or `PropertyTriggers`. Define a style for the `ToolTip` which contains the `DataTrigger`:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=code}">
            <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip>
                    <Tooltip.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=grouping}" Value="Search Results">
                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Path=grouping}"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers> 
                        </Style> 
                    </ToolTip.Style>
                </ToolTip>
            </TextBlock.ToolTip>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

[MSDN says:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.triggers.aspx)

> Note that the collection of triggers established on an element only
>   supports EventTrigger, not property triggers (Trigger). If you require
>   property triggers, you must place these within a style or template and
>   then assign that style or template to the element either directly
>   through the Style property, or indirectly through an implicit style
>   reference.

That doesn't describe your problem directly, but read it as: *Set Triggers in styles.*

This article gets more specific: [Dr. WPF Blog](http://drwpf.com/blog/category/triggers/)

> There is also a Triggers collection on FrameworkElement, but it can
>   only contain event triggers… not property or data triggers.

Comment: Thanks. The compile-error is gone however the code you posted didn't work as expected. The tooltip is not showing any text. A blank gray box is showing up--and it's showing up regardless of the grouping value.

Comment: There's something wrong with your DataBinding then. Are any BindingErrors logged in the output console?

Comment: There are no binding errors logged. I tried playing around with the binding and the values and nothing worked. This is driving me nuts.

Comment: Can you upload a sample project?

Comment: Sadly, no. This is part of a big application and taking only the piece I posted above into a separate project will take a lot of time. I think I will just leave the data trigger out. I'll just display the tooltip regardless of the my grouping. This has taken me more time that I wanted for a minor functionality. Thanks for your time. I'll get back to this later when I have more time to work on it.